# Python class doesn't change class variable

Tags: python, pandas, oop, multiprocessing

Hi I am writing a simple script with multiple processes. Here is class that I am using:

```
class WorkerProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, batch):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.batch = batch
        self.data_frame = pd.DataFrame()

    def run(self):
        temp = []
        for item in self.batch:
            temp.append(item)
        self.data_frame = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=temp[0].keys())
        print('empty: ', self.data_frame.empty) # everything is fine
```

Later I start processes and join them:

```
    workers = []
    for i in range(max_processes):
        try:
            batch = batches_data.pop()
            workers.append(WorkerProcess(batch))
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()

    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()

    for worker in workers:
        print(worker.data_frame) # it is empty
```

When I print data_frame it is empty even though is was changed in run() function.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not to be rude, but did you make sure to call `WorkerProces().run()`?

Comment: yup, I get the print from run and it prints "empty: False". This is the response I get when running with 2 processes: empty:  False
empty:  False
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)` That seems like an odd way to call the parent class `__init__()` method.  Shouldn't you be using `super()`?

Answer (score 0):

Processes do not share their memory address space. Thanks to Linux process forking strategy, you usually get the feeling the child process share its memory with the parent but in reality it's a copy.

This means that changes in the child process will not be reflected in its parent (or in any other process).

The Python multiprocessing library offers several mechanisms to [share memory between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).